# Why use Object.create inside this reduce callback?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

So while working on #19 of this fine tutorial - http://jhusain.github.io/learnrx/, I find that the exercise works without using Object.create. (See the commented-out lines)

#### 1. So what is the point of creating that copy of the accumulatedMap? Other than showing that it is possible...

```
function() {
    var videos = [
        {
            "id": 65432445,
            "title": "The Chamber"
        },
        {
            "id": 675465,
            "title": "Fracture"
        },
        {
            "id": 70111470,
            "title": "Die Hard"
        },
        {
            "id": 654356453,
            "title": "Bad Boys"
        }
    ];

    // Expecting this output...
    // [
    //     {
    //         "65432445": "The Chamber",
    //         "675465": "Fracture",
    //         "70111470": "Die Hard",
    //         "654356453": "Bad Boys"
    //     }
    // ]
    return videos.
        reduce(function(accumulatedMap, video) {

            // Object.create() makes a fast copy of the accumulatedMap by
            // creating a new object and setting the accumulatedMap to be the
            // new object's prototype.
            // Initially the new object is empty and has no members of its own,
            // except a pointer to the object on which it was based. If an
            // attempt to find a member on the new object fails, the new object
            // silently attempts to find the member on its prototype. This
            // process continues recursively, with each object checking its
            // prototype until the member is found or we reach the first object
            // we created.
            // If we set a member value on the new object, it is stored
            // directly on that object, leaving the prototype unchanged.
            // Object.create() is perfect for functional programming because it
            // makes creating a new object with a different member value almost
            // as cheap as changing the member on the original object!

            //var copyOfAccumulatedMap = Object.create(accumulatedMap);

            //copyOfAccumulatedMap[video.id] = video.title;
            accumulatedMap[video.id] = video.title;

          //return copyOfAccumulatedMap;
            return accumulatedMap;
        },
        // Use an empty map as the initial value instead of the first item in
        // the list.
        {});
}
```

#### 2 And if you *do* do it using `copyOfAccumulatedMap`, you end up with an object like this

[image]

which looks intriguing, but is puzzling because I cannot do the same thing with this code here

```
var fruit = { 'taste' : 3 };

var apple = Object.create(fruit);
    apple['size'] = 7;

var apple = Object.create(fruit);
    apple['hardness'] = 6;

var apple = Object.create(fruit);
    apple['weight'] = 10;

console.log(apple.taste);
console.log(apple.size);     // undefined as I would expect
console.log(apple.hardness); // undefined as I would expect
console.log(apple.weight);
```

So what is it that allows the object in the exercise to have all the chained prototypes but doesn't allow my apple to do the same?

Comment: you keep clobbering old `apple`s, so of course they won't show up...

Comment: my point exactly - the exercise keeps clobbering copyOfAccumulatedMap - so how does it remember that chain of Bad Boys, Die Hard, Fracture, etc... ?

Comment: No it doesn't clobber it. It returns it; so it will keep that reference as `video`, and then add that object's information to the next created object.

Comment: ah... so it is being clobbered, but not before returning its data to be regenerated. Like Spock in StarTrek3! Thanks!

Comment: @dwilbank at first glance, there's some horrible practices in this tutorial you linked (http://jhusain.github.io/learnrx/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You kind of answered your own question: `Object.create` makes that prototype chain. `Object.create` takes as its parameter the prototype object for the object being created.

```
var copyOfAccumulatedMap = Object.create(accumulatedMap);
```

The old `accumulatedMap` is being used as the prototype for `copyOfAccumulatedMap`. Then copy is returned, to be the `accumulatedMap` the next time through.

Comment: the prototype object it takes as its parameter does not have these chained (nested?) prototypes though. It is an object with 4 key-value pairs.

Comment: It's taking the previous object as its prototype. That builds the chain. I've updated the answer to explain in a bit more detail.

Comment: the last line there straightens everything out regarding question#2. Thanks!